# Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Out of Memory

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am getting below error when I try to deploy my application in IBM worklight environment. Suddenly I am facing this error but earlier it worked well.

Could you please any one help me, is there any settings I have modify in the project.

Error is :

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.100 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://ADMINIB-9PGB9N2.in.ibm.com:10080/GDMSLoginApp/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0009I: The application GDMSLoginApp has stopped successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.061 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ADMINIB-9PGB9N2.in.ibm.com:10080/GDMSLoginApp/
[ERROR   ] out of memory processing logC:\GDMS\GDMSmobileMenu2\WorklightServerConfig\servers\worklight\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\72\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\GDMSLoginApp\GDMSLoginApp/hsqldb/WRKLGHT line: 4
Java heap space
[ERROR   ] could not reopen database
Out of Memory
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0188E: Failed to connect to HSQL database : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Out of Memory) [project GDMSLoginApp]
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /GDMSLoginApp [project GDMSLoginApp]
Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GDMS/GDMSmobileMenu2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GDMS/GDMSmobileMenu2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GDMS/GDMSmobileMenu2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/GDMS/GDMSmobileMenu2/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Out of Memory)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application GDMSLoginApp started in 1.834 seconds.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An execption occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Out of Memory
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:305)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Out of Memory
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the following from the log:

> Logged Exception: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Out of Memory

Try increasing Eclipse's available memory.

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open eclipse.ini, located in the Eclipse installation folder
3. Find in the file the following (the numbers may differ):

   -vmargs
   -Xms128m
   -Xmx512m

Increase the numbers to 512 or 1024 and re-open Eclipse.

Comment: Hi Idan, Thank you for the help. But still I am getting same error. I have modified the eclipse.ini file as below.                                              -vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m       Can you suggest is there any thing wrongI am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue despite changing my memory settings within eclipse.ini. The problem was resolved by performing the following steps:

1. Stop your Liberty Worklight Development Server by right-clicking on it in the Servers tab
2. Right-click on it and select "Clean..."
3. Start your Liberty server again
4. Re-install your .adapters and .wlapps as needed
5. Try again